# How to avoid duplicate POJOs in different web services, Java

Tags: java, rest, web-services, dry, pojo

I have a webapp with multiple Spring services (they each have their own ear and web-controllers) and they talk to each other via REST calls. Some of the different services use the same data POJOs. The existing code just has duplicates of those data objects in different services.

For example, my `/users` service has a `myApp.users.UserData` object, and my `/emails` service calls `/users/{userId}` and holds the result as a `myApp.emails.UserData` object. Both of these objects are identical.

The problem here is I have to keep `myApp.emails.UserData` and `myApp.users.UserData` in sync, since in reality they represent the same info and are meant to be the "same" class. Say I update the name of a field in `emails.UserData`, I better remember to update it in `users.UserData`, otherwise things will break.

I know I could make a shared dependency called something like `SharedDataObjects`, define `myApp.sharedDataObjects.UserData` there, and just have both versions refer to that. For some reason, though, my gut feeling is that this is not a good solution... (maybe it is though?)

Are there any better ways of approaching this issue? Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way the webapp structured, and if so how could that be addressed?

Comment: "(maybe it is though?)" It is. Your names are bad, but plenty of apps are structured that. Call it something like "model".

Comment: Didn't think too much about the naming at this point, just wrote the first thing that came into my head. BTW, just clarifying, the names here aren't actually what things are called in the app (i.e. app is not actually called myApp), I'm just simplifying for the sake of the question. If You recommend calling it something like "model" is the idea that the "model" component would hold _all_ POJO classes in my app? I don't think having to update a common dependency in all of my services whenever I want to make a change to something that only applies to one service is a good idea...

Comment: Following the example above -- I shouldn't have to redeploy or recompile /users if I change something like myApp.model.EmailContents.subject to myApp.model.EmailContents.subjectLine

Comment: "*is the idea that the "model" component would hold all POJO classes in my app?*" Not necessarily. The shared ones.

Comment: Btw, feel free to post Your comment as an answer. It's short, but it answers the question. I'm happy to mark the question as answered if nothing more in-depth comes in the next few days

Comment: "Not necessarily. The shared ones". Ah thanks for the clarification, makes more sense now

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but do all services exist in the same module (Maven/Gradle), or different modules? If they all exist in the same module then you don't even need another dependency, as you stated. Just throw the shared stuff in a common package. e.g. `com.foo.model.common.User`, `com.foo.model.emailservice.Email`

Comment: You're right, I didn't specify. Each service is its own Maven project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always tempting to spot duplicated (or nearly duplicated) code and try to eliminate the duplication. An obvious path in that direction is to make a shared library (or module) and have different services (or applications) depend on it.

Doing so, however, increases coupling between services/applications/modules, which has its own set of drawbacks in many contexts. Especially in a microservices architecture*, that kind of coupling often leads to headaches. It can even lead to loss of the value of using microservices* in the first place.

If two services* are supposed to be independent but integrated, they have an integration protocol of some kind. For REST services, for example, that's almost always HTTP and JSON**. By introducing a shared library, you have coupled them in a binary way, separate from (and more binding than) HTTP and JSON. Not a good situation; experience has taught many of us that painful lesson.

Instead, focus on the public interfaces that each service exposes, and use appropriate versioning to evolve those interfaces when needed. Don't worry about some duplicate-looking classes, especially if they're anemic POJOs; that's a minor concern compared to a tightly-coupled set of services that are supposed to be independent.

Not that shared code libraries are inherently bad, they're not and they have true value in many ways. Rather, my point is you need to make sure each service maintains its own definition of what important things are, so that each can remain as independent as possible - and evolve independently as much as possible.

By the way, this is somewhat related to the concept of [Bounded Contexts](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html); you might want to read more about it if you're working with microservices*.

---

*or whatever you call your architecture of independently-managed services/modules/apps

** Could also be some kind of messaging/queueing platform, as another example

Comment: So I guess I failed to mention that these services are already coupled in the sense that there are common homemade utils that they share. The other, more important thing, is that we use Spring and Jaxb to automatically parse the results of a REST call. So when emails calls /user/{userId} (which returns a user.UserData object), it can just immediately the return value of the REST call as an email.UserData. But this only works if user.UserData and email.UserData are completely identical. So I'm sort of in a situation where the shared objects _can't_ evolve independently.

Comment: Or should I have a mapper in each project that transforms one type to the other? This seems like an immense I amount of boilerplate (I have at least two dozen such shared files amongst my services), and there's the technical issue of I need a method in emails that takes a user.UserData and returns an email.UserData, but since emails service doesn't contain users.UserData nor depend on /users, I can't actually reference user.UserData

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure how to build the interfaces, and especially not in a way that adds too much bloat

Comment: Shared utils (via libraries) is not the same as shared model classes; one is standard reuse without coupling, the other is binary coupling and a much nastier problem.

Comment: The JSON (or XML or any "tolerant," non-binary) representation of a data model is the interface between REST or message-based services. The impl classes on both sides of an integration can change independently as long as the JSON remains compatible. For example, if you decide to change the `hairColor` property of your Person model from a string to an enum, both sides don't have to know that. There are ways to evolve/migrate that interface, too. Some things won't work, but in my experience, most reasonable evolution is doable, especially with appropriate versioning in the APIs/messages.

Comment: With binary dependencies, the only migration/evolution path is usually "update to the new version of that shared library."